# What is the difference in how shah and schchah are written (by hand) in practice?

Tags: буквы, алфавит

The capitalized forms would likely be indistinguishable and the lowercase forms *are* identical according to this resource (as noted on *Pinterest*).  Naturally there must be an actual difference when a native speaker of *cyrillic* based languages jots them down. Can someone do exactly that and take a screenshot and provide a quick note/explanation?

[image]

Note: the appropriate tag for this is *кириллица* but that tag does not presently exist.

Comment: Always cross-check any reference ;)

Comment: Sorry, it took me a little while to process the question. "Shah is a monarch... who is <Schchah>?" But I got it in the end :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is an incorrect (and poor quality) picture. These letters look different in every script. Like this:

Ш ш

Щ щ

## Ш ш

## Щ щ

[image: Ш Щ]

Answer (score 1):

Here are handwritten examples of both.

[image]